# jquery multi-step form with another nested multi-step form

Tags: jquery, forms, tabs, wizard

I'm coding a form wizard but i'm having some problems with it.

What i want to do is a form with 3 tabs, one of this tabs (tab2) with dynamic tabs(subtabs).

[image]

Tab 1 has 3 input texts to add new "subtabs".
Tab 2 has "subtabs" or nested wizard.The subtabs are created in the previous step.
Tab 3 is the final tab with some imputs.

So user enters the registration form and starts with tab1. Then adds 1-n subtabs (campers attending a child camp), something like camper 1, camper 2, camper 3...
Then when he finish adding subtabs goes to main tab2.
Here there're the subtabs added previously: camper1, camper2, camper3 each with a LOT of fields.
When he clicks next goes to subtab1, then subtab2, then subtab3 and when there aren't more subtabs it goes to main Tab3.

The code is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/4ZPbC/9/)

The html:

```
<div id="form-wizard" class="wizard">
    <div class="steps">
        <div data-target="#st1" class="active"><a href="#">Step 1</a>
        </div>
        <div data-target="#st2"><a href="#">Step 2(with subitems)</a>
        </div>
        <div data-target="#st3"><a href="#">Step 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-steps">
        <div data-target="#sb1" class="active"><a href="#">Substep1</a>
        </div>
        <div data-target="#sb2"><a href="#">Substep2</a>
        </div>
        <div data-target="#sb3"><a href="#">Substep3</a>
        </div>
        <div data-target="#sb4"><a href="#">Substep4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="step-content">
    <div class="step-pane active" id="st1">
        <p>This is the first step in this wizard example...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="step-pane" id="st2">
        <div class="sub-step-content">
            <div class="sub-step-pane active" id="sb1">
                <p>This is the SUB-STEP 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-step-pane" id="sb2">
                <p>This is the SUB-STEP 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-step-pane" id="sb3">
                <p>This is the SUB-STEP 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-step-pane" id="sb4">
                <p>This is the SUB-STEP 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-pane" id="st3">
        <input type='text' name='name' id='name' placeholder='Enter Your Name' />
        <input type='text' name='name' id='name' placeholder='Enter Your Name' />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="step-nav"> <a href="#" id="prev-step">Prev</a>
 <a href="#" id="next-step">Next</a>

</div>
<p class="debug">debug</p>
```

And the jquery is this:

```
var subPanelId = '#st2';

$('#next-step').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var currentTab = $('.steps .active'),
        currentSubTab = $('.sub-steps .active'),
        totalSubtabs = $('.sub-step-pane').size(),
        lastSubTab = $('.sub-step-pane:last');

    if (currentTab.data('target') != subPanelId) {

        moveToTab('.steps', '.step-content', 'next');

    } else {

        if (currentSubTab.index() < (totalSubtabs - 1)) {

            moveToTab('.sub-steps', '.sub-step-content', 'next');

        } else {

            moveToTab('.steps', '.step-content', 'next');

        }
    }

});

$('#prev-step').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var currentTab = $('.steps .active'),
        currentSubTab = $('.sub-steps .active');

    if (currentTab.data('target') != subPanelId && currentSubTab.index() > 0) {

        moveToTab('.steps', '.step-content', 'prev');

    } else {


        if (currentSubTab.index() > 0) {

            moveToTab('.sub-steps', '.sub-step-content', 'prev');

        } else {

            moveToTab('.steps', '.step-content', 'prev');

        }

    }
});

function activateSub(currentTab) {
    if (currentTab == subPanelId || $(currentTab).parent().hasClass('sub-step-content')) $('.sub-steps').show();
    else $('.sub-steps').hide();
}

function moveToTab(tabContainer, tabContent, dir) {

    var totalTabs = $(tabContainer).find('div').size();

    currentTab = $(tabContainer).find('.active');

    if (currentTab.index() < (totalTabs - 1)) {

        currentTab.removeClass('active');

        if (dir == 'next') {
            currentTab.next()
                .addClass('active');
        } else {
            currentTab.prev()
                .addClass('active');
        }
        $('.debug').html(currentTab.next().data('target'));

        $(tabContent).find('div')
            .removeClass('active');

        if (dir == 'next') {
            $(tabContent)
                .find(currentTab.data('target'))
                .next()
                .addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(tabContent)
                .find(currentTab.data('target'))
                .prev()
                .addClass('active');
        }

        activateSub(currentTab.next().data('target'));

    }
}
```

Some problems in the actual code:
- When I add a new subtab it shows under the tab2 but the content doesn't show.
- When I reach the last tab it stop working.Prev/next buttons doesn't work anymore.

prev/next navigation for tabs were working in a previous version. You can take a look to see how they work:
[old fiddle with tab navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/4ZPbC/6/)

At the end I have to save the data.I'm not saving the data, just sending it to a backend developer to save it. How would you do it?

How can I make it work?